# Get date in postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have a column with type numeric which consist date in timestamp format. I need to get a date in 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss' format.
My code:

```
select start_dt_timestamp, to_timestamp(start_dt_timestamp/1000) as dt 
  from tmp_table
```

In result:

| start_dt_timestamp | dt |
| --- | --- |
| 1554747217660018 | 51237-12-23 16:07:40 |

`51237-12-23 16:07:40` - is not correct date. What I need to do get correct answer?

Comment: you should show what start_dt_timestamp value is for understand what is wrong

Comment: Is the `/1000` correct, or should it be `/1000000` or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column is in microseconds, not milliseconds; divide it by 1000000 instead of 1000:

```
select start_dt_timestamp, to_timestamp(start_dt_timestamp/1000000) as dt 
  from tmp_table
```

That should give 2019-04-09 04:13:37

Comment: BTW `to_timestamp(start_dt_timestamp/1000000.0)` will produce the more accurate value

Comment: Or, if rounding to whole seconds is desired: `to_timestamp((start_dt_timestamp+500000)/1000000)`